# Increasing vertical space between segments in base R

Tags: r, plot, confidence-interval

I'm trying to increase the space between each segment for each successive interval to avoid overplotting. Not sure how to approach this so that it will increment vertically in the loop.

Here is my code and some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(200)
x <- rnorm(100, 10) 
truemean <- mean(x)

mat <- replicate(100, t.test(sample(x, rep = T))$conf.int) 
mat <- t(mat)

myfunc <- function(mat, truemean) {

  plot(x = c(min(mat[ , 1]), max(mat[ , 2])), 
       y = c(1, 100), 
       type = "n", 
       xlab = "0:100",
       ylab = "0:100")

  abline(v = truemean)

  for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {

    if (mat[i, 1] <= truemean & mat[i, 2] >= truemean) {

      segments(x0 = mat[i, 1], y0 = i, 
               x1 = mat[i, 2], y1 = i, 
               col = "blue",
               lwd = 2)

    } else {

      segments(x0 = mat[i, 1], y0 = i, 
               x1 = mat[i, 2], y1 = i, 
               col = "red", 
               lwd = 2) 

    }

  }

}

myfunc(mat, truemean)
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do aside from setting the line width smaller (ie `lwd = 0.5`) or the plot taller. [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/82hjVCl.png)?

Comment: Yes but I thought that there might be be a way to add each segment so it moves upward by some constant spacing value.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly add anything you want in the segment call, but I'm not sure what you are asking. First we can greatly simplify your code:

```
set.seed(200)
x <- rnorm(100, 10) 
truemean <- mean(x)

mat <- replicate(100, t.test(sample(x, rep = T))$conf.int) 
mat <- t(mat)

yval <- seq(dim(mat)[1])
clr <- ifelse(mat[, 1] <= truemean & mat[, 2] >= truemean, "blue", "red") 
plot(NA, xlim=c(min(mat[ , 1]), max(mat[ , 2])), ylim=c(0, length(yval)), type="n",
     xlab="Conf Int", ylab="Trials")
abline(v=truemean)
segments(mat[, 1], yval, mat[, 2], yval, col=clr)
```

This produces the following plot:

### [image: ConfIntPlot]

You could replace `yval` with `yval+.1` in the `segments` function to shift everything up. If there are so many lines that they overlap you can increase the height of the plot to make more room.